# Implement SWT(Stroke Width Transform) algorithm in Android

Tags: android, algorithm, image-processing

This is the algorithm which I need to port to Android(http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~turkel/imagepapers/text_detection.pdf).

Surfed the web and found this C implementation which seems to be good. 
http://libccv.org/lib/ccv-swt/

I need to port this to Android first before use. But I have no experience with that kind of stuff in Android. what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using Android NDK. I had to write a wrapper for C library and call the JNI method from Java.